# Automatically monitor executable files in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

It is possible to launch an exe file using a third party program through the context menu.

My problem is that an exe file might be triggered by a script or by another application on which I don't have control.

**How can I force every executable files to run using a third party program ?**

`Comodo Programs Manager` has a running service that automatically monitor any installation of exe file. How do they proceed ? Is it possible to listen to specific events ?

I thought I could use a **BATCH** script by :

- replacing the default registry key of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command` by something like `path\to\my\script.bat "%1 %*"`
- in the script, do custom stuff like logging and then call the executable :

  ```
  ...

  echo %DATE% %TIME% %* >> "somewhere\logging.txt"

  ...

  :2
  @REM Monitor file (same as context menu open with ...)
  path/to/monitoring.exe %*
  goto end

  ...
  ```

This would work for PDF file for example. But it obviously doesn't work for executables because `path/to/monitoring.exe %*`, when executed, is running the script again ... and I can't find a way to launch an executable without going through the registry file association.

**Is it something possible ?**

Comment: How about adding a `shift`?

Comment: Don't see how `shift` could help me ... Could you give more details ?

Comment: As I couldn't move the question (I tried to do a close procedure as mentioned in a meta site). Here is a duplicate : http://superuser.com/questions/843060/automatically-run-executable-files-with-third-party-program-script-in-windows